# Pluralization issue in the blog post comments count

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, plurals

There is a pluralization issue in the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/)'s comments count.
When there is only one comment for the blog post, it is showing as `1 comments`.
It should be displayed as `1 comment`.

[image: Blog post comment]

Also the same pluralization issue in the individual blog post's comments section (bottom of the blog post)

[image: Individual post]

Comment: New platform, old bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pluralization issue has been fixed in the blog home page and in the individual blog post's comments section.

**Screenshots for reference:**

[image: home page]

[image: individual blog post]